# Windows equivalent to Secure Pipes SOCKS proxy GUI

Tags: windows, ssh, socks-proxy

I would like to setup a SOCKS proxy using SSH on Windows for a colleague who is not that technically savvy (so preferably no terminal or command line).

On OSX, we have a nice GUI for this called Secure Pipes:

https://www.opoet.com/pyro/

Is there a Windows equivalent with some kind of GUI that lives in the Windows tray, and shows you "green" when connected and "grey" when disconnected? I have Googled extensively but only found terminal-based solutions and abandoned & sketchy shareware.

Thanks!

Comment: PuTTY should do that.

Comment: I was hoping for a tool that had a GUI that lived in the tray, similar to how commercial VPN clients work.

Answer (score 1):

One option you could use for this would be [MobaXTerm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) . Amongst other features it has a nice Tunnels GUI which helps in setting up SSH tunnels and has a start/stop button on the page.